# AWS API creation delay?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently using aws-amplify for react native. I'm using the API command to do HTTP requests and I was able to call a GET method API that I created few months ago. The thing is when I call a function that's freshly made, it keeps telling me that the "Api 'API name' doesn't exist". I tried to see if there was any typo, but nothing. I also created a GET method API with the exact same code as the one that was working but same result (api doesn't exist). Has anyone also run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your sample code including the object you're passing to `Amplify.configure(object)` and also the GET call which includes the name (`API.get(name, path, options)()`? You'll need to ensure that the name is in the `endpoints[]` array of your configuration object per the documentation and that this matches the name passed in your method call. For more information see this page: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/api_guide.md